# Call to a member function have_posts() on null in

Tags: wordpress

i use this code for get id of the post in wordpress:

```
public function findAll() {


    if ( have_posts() ) {

        the_post();

        $id = the_ID();
    }


    return $id;
}
```

But the following error occurs:

Fatal error: Call to a member function have_posts() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp\wp-includes\query.php on line 767

Comment: Where have you put this code? Which hook or which template file?

Comment: In the separate file in the plugin folder to get id

Comment: how do you call that separate file? it is decisive factor. if you use it in wrong place, then of course it would not work

Comment: it seems you are calling code in a file which have_posts are not reacheable

Comment: File path is defined in plugin and call by this url : localhost/api/
now , how to get post Id in api file?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong check below working one

```
       if ( have_posts() ) :
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
           $id= get_the_ID();
         endwhile;
      else :
         echo wpautop( 'Sorry, no posts were found' );
      endif;
```

Comment: You are right, why are you downvoted ? I've upvoted you